# Localization file for Web Application. How implement correct structure?

Tags: localization, web, web-deployment

For example, we have simply web page with next elements:

page title(`<title>My Page </title>`);

page title (`<h2>Hello! It is My Page!</h2>`);

table with:

table name (`This is a table!`);

table row names (`<th>id</th>, <th>Name</th>, <th>Description</th>`);

Some links (`<a>Back</a>, <a>Exit</a>`);

As you see - all very simply.

My question next:

**what the best practices for names of localized variables?**

Example 1:

```
title1 =My Page;

title2 = Hello! It is My Page;

table_name=This is a table;

id=Id;

name=Name;

description=Description;

back=Back;

exit=Exit;
```

Example2:

```
page.title=My Page;

h2.title =Hello! It is My Page;

table.name = This is a table;

table.row.id.name = Id;

table.row.name.name = Name;

table.row.description.name = Description;

link.back = Back;

link.exit = Exit;
```

Example 3:

```
indexPage.page.title =My page;

indexPage.h2.title = Hello! This is My Page;

indexPage.table.name = This is a table;

indexPage.table.row.id.name = Id;

indexPage.table.row.name.name = Name;

indexPage.table.row.description.name = Description;

indexPage.link.back = Back;

indexPage.link.exit = Exit;
```

If my Application contains only one page - I think, that example 1 - perfect variant, but..
If I have many pages, many different elements on page example 1 -real fail, you agree with me?

therefore, I am trying to create the most successful, flexible, fast and simple algorithm for naming locale variables.

I think, that Example 3 - the most good variant, but variable name - very long. I am not sure - that it is very flexible and simple...

So, I repeat my question, **what practices you used for localized variables name?**

Answer (score 0):

Web apps are typically localized using the infrastructure provided by your development framework. You didn't mention how you are building your application, but surely if you search the documentation of your framework (e.g. ASP.NET, RoR, PHP) for "localization", you should be able to find all the information you need.